# iTunesconnect - The email address you entered already belongs to a Sandbox account. To continue, enter a different email address

Tags: email, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes, account

I am able to add my Apple ID account with Paid developer account as role of Admin in developer.apple.com

But I am unable to add my Apple ID account in iTunesConnect user and roles, as error prompts "The email address you entered already belongs to a Sandbox account. To continue, enter a different email address."
[image]
P.S: My Apple ID  isn’t linked with Sandbox testers.